# How to update skype contacts between android and windows desktop?

Tags: sync, skype, contacts

I have skype installed on my android phone and on my windows desktop.

When I add a nr in the skype on Android it is not showing up on the skype on my windows desktop.

In android I did Settings > General > Accounts > Skype > Sync now.
In windows I don't understand how to force a sync.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Your contact list is stored online nor locally on your PC.

Comment: So I have to maintain the contact list on different installations manually?

Comment: No;  Your contact list is stored online connected to your MS account, not locally, how did you needed to maintain contact lists manually from my comment?

Comment: Because you not give a solution so the conclusion is then it is not possible which means I have to add the same address in two devices.

Comment: Sure; do that; I didn't provide a solution because your I didn't need to your contact list is stored in the cloud and requires no steps to sync your contact list on your PC and Android phone that happens automatically

Comment: Ramhound, thxs for your feedback but this is exactly the question. It is not working !

Comment: I make changes to my contacts on one computer, and several minutes later I'm still not seeing those changes on my other computer (the one I actually want to make skype calls from.) Using up-to-date Linux Skype.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing the same thing until I quit Skype on the destination computer (the one I wanted contact changes to by synced TO). Then the changes showed up.

Be careful - skype is hard to actually quit. Closing the window won't do it. You have to go to the pull down and select 'File / Quit' to make it actually quit.

Answer (score 0):

After force quit desktop app and reopening it, the problem was gone and both of them now sync correctly.